# Error: must be a static non-member function. Templated Class

Tags: c++

I'm trying to overload the assignment operator inside of my templated class. I keep getting an error saying that my method must be a static non-member function.

```
template <class Type>
class linkedQueueType
{
public:
    linkedQueueType<Type>& operator=(const linkedQueueType<Type>&)const;
      //Overload the assignment operator.
...
};
```

```
template <class Type>
const linkedQueueType<Type>& operator=(const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue)
{
    //Write the definition of to overload the assignment operator
    
    if(this != &otherQueue) // if me (pointer) is not equal to the address of otherQueue
    {
        copyList(otherQueue); // make a copy of the otherQueue
    }
    return *this; // return me (pointer) dereferenced
```

I've tried adding "const" to the end and beginning of my method but nothing seems to work. I've gotten this same method to work in a separate project but it does not seem to want to work in this file.

All of my code is inside of the same header file that includes my class and methods within it. I've had problems with templated classes not compiling if I had a separate .h and .cpp file.

All my methods are public inside of the class.

Comment: What are the `const` supposed to achieve anyway? You only need to get rid of the `const` at the end of the declaration and the one at the beginning of the definition. And also, the syntax for the definition is missing `linkedQueueType<Type>::` before `operator=` as always required for out-of-class class template member definitions.

Comment: It helps considerably if you can include the *exact* error text you're getting.

Comment: Not sure how you can assign to a `const`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] through https://godbolt.org/  Also assignment operator with const doesn't make sense in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code in my MSVC compiler and it did give me a error saying the operator should be a member function. So I replaced your code with :

```
template <class Type>
class linkedQueueType
{
public:
    linkedQueueType<Type>& operator=(const linkedQueueType<Type>&);
    //Overload the assignment operator.
    ...
};
```

```
template <class Type>
linkedQueueType<Type>& linkedQueueType<Type>::operator=(const linkedQueueType<Type>& otherQueue)
{
    //Write the definition of to overload the assignment operator

    if (this != &otherQueue) // if me (pointer) is not equal to the address of otherQueue
    {
        copyList(otherQueue); // make a copy of the otherQueue
    }
    return *this; // return me (pointer) dereferenced
}
```

this worked fine for me.

**Changes I've made :**

1. I've removed the const from the operator, because I don't think anyone uses const on a assignment operator.
2. I've defined the operator as a member function in the implementation, because that was what you missed this whole time.

I hope that works for you as well. Do tell me if it does work or not!

Comment: I am no longer getting an error thanks to you! I tried to remove the const and it just didn't seem to work. After implamenting your code I am not getting that same error message! Thank you so much:)                                                                                                                                                I'm relatively new to programming, so I wasn't aware that adding "const" wouldn't really do anything. Thank you for the heads up and I won't add const anymore for an overloading operator.

Comment: instead of thanks, you could make sure not to make the same mistake again. i've written what mistake you made.

Comment: You're right. I'll make sure to not make the same simple (stupid) mistake again. Thank you.